# RoleStore throws error with StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, structuremap, user-roles

When i try to use Asp.Net Identity RoleStore and use StructureMap as DI container, the UserStore works fine, but the RoleStore throws up an error at compilation itself.

```
//works fine
cfg.For<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Use<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();

//does NOT work
cfg.For<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>>().Use<RoleStore<IdentityRole>>();
```

throws the following error

> The type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.RoleStore'
>   cannot be used as type parameter 'TConcreteType' in the generic type
>   or method
>   'StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Expressions.CreatePluginFamilyExpression.Use()'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.RoleStore'
>   to
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IRoleStore'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `RoleStore<TRole>` is not implemented from `IRoleStore<TRole>`. Actually it is implemented from `IRoleStore<TRole, TKey>`. Therefore try this instead:

```
cfg.For<IRoleStore<IdentityRole,string>>().Use<RoleStore<IdentityRole>>();
```